# I can't get my data to display from firebase to my node js client

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display the data stored in my database onto the client side but I am having a hard time figuring this out.

I am able to display the data within my console in my terminal in JSON format

e.g.

```
{ '-L32RrW6PaBF162cyfDv': { article: { body: 'Test Body', title: 'Test Title' } },
  '-L32UMeos7o2bwtPMVTF': { article: { body: 'test', title: 'test' } },.....
```

but when I try to display it with a for loop in my jade template nothing seems to show up. I was hoping if someone can point out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you and let me know if anyone needs more information to answer this question.

here is the part where I am trying to retrieve and display the data (all the routes are working properly):

```
// Add Articles Route
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('articles')
  let articlesRef = ref.child('article')
  let articleRef = articlesRef.key
  articlesRef = ref.once('value')
    .then((snap) => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
  res.render('articles', {
    title: 'Add Article',
    articles: articlesRef
  })
})
```

Here is the jade template file. Only the last 3 lines of code should be relevant to this question:

```
extends layout

block content
    .row
    h1 #{title}
    hr
    form(method='POST', action='/articles')
        #form-group
            label Title
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        br
        #form-group
            label Body
            textarea.form-control(name='body')
            br
            input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Submit')
    br
    br
    ul
        each article in articles
            li= article
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Add Articles Route
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('articles')
  let articlesRef = ref.child('article')
  let articleRef = articlesRef.key
  articlesRef = ref.once('value')
    .then((snap) => {
      console.log(snap.val());
      res.render('articles', {
        title: 'Add Article',
        articles: snap.val()
      })
    })
})
```

You need to wait for the actual value to be fetched before you can render it, thus moving it inside the `then` and using `snap.val()`.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much @Michael Bleigh. I got this working but it is now returning [object Object] for each <li>. I tried to use "articles: JSON.parse(snap.val())" but it still shows as [object Object]. Could you possibly let me know how to display it correctly?

Comment: Apologies, I was able to figure it out. I had to use JSON.stringify() in my jade template. Thank you again for the help. You are a lifesaver.